# shell waits for input after orphan process was reaped by init

Tags: c, linux, bash, unix, ubuntu

The following program calls `fork()` and intends to produce an orphan process. It works properly and the orphan process is reaped by process `init` (examined by command `ps`). But why bash seems wait for input?

```
    ...    
    if ((pid = fork() < 0) {
        err_sys("fork error");    /* err_sys is declared in apue.h */
    } else if (pid == 0) {
        /* sleep to ensure that parent process terminates first */
        printf("child process: %d\n", getpid());
        sleep(2);
        exit(0);
    }
    printf("parent process\n");
    exit(0);
}
```

Execute the program

```
$ ./a.out
parent process
$ child process: 4787
_    <= shell stops here until I hit Ctrl-C
        (the underscore is just for demostration)
```

Note: I'm using Ubuntu 11.10.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Yes. It works too. But I don't understand why this was so.

Comment: Bet if you just hit return instead of `ctrl-c` that will work too -- which is Joachim's point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shell is not waiting anymore than usual when it displays a prompt. The problem (if you can call it that) is that the child process prints some output followed by a newline. This newline is printed but the shell doesn't print a new prompt. That's all. Just write commands as usual and it will work.